# Down state iOS button mobile safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari

How can I style my buttons to use my defined "down" (`:active`) state when touched in Mobile Safari instead of just getting that semitransparent overlay applied?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable the highlight, you just have to reset its color value:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
```